# iOS: Limit screen orientation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller

I have an app which has a rootViewController and several child views.  I want to lock the screen orientation to portrait for all of the views except one.  The one view is an UIPageViewController which display's several web views and it needs to be landscape.

I can force it into landscape mode with the following code in my viewDidLoad:

```
NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];
```

I can't seem to prevent the view from transitioning back to portrait on rotation.  I need to lock it into landscape mode.

The following code does not seem to prevent rotation:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
   return NO;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
   return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape);
}

- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window{
return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
```

}

I'm targeting 7.1 and up.  What am I missing?

Comment: Is your viewController a navigation view controller? If yes, you need to lock the orientation on the navigation view controller and not your view controller

Comment: I've implemented into my rootViewController  with orientation set for portrait as well.  It still changes upon rotation.

Comment: try placing `NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];` in `viewDidAppear` not `viewDidLoad`